# Spring Boot EnvironmentAware not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have written a Spring Boot Application where several classes are implementing the `EnvironmentAware` interface.

The `EnvironmentAware.setEnvironment()` method is being called on the `ApplicationConfiguration` class upon loading, but it IS NOT being called when it is implemented in the other classes.  (I wrote another app where this works and have configured it the same way I have this app.)

The other class where I have implemented the `EnvironmentAware` interface looks like:

```
@Component("merchandisingMasterDataItemsProxy")
@Scope("singleton")
@Configurable
public class MerchandisingMasterDataItemsProxy extends BaseProxy implements EnvironmentAware {

private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
private String base_url;

@Override
// THIS NEVER GETS CALLED
public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}

@Autowired
public MerchandisingMasterDataItemsProxy(RestTemplate restTemplateMerchandisingItems) {

    super(restTemplateMerchandisingItems);

    // ENVIRONMENT IS NULL HERE :(
    this.base_url = environment.getProperty(BaseConfig.VCAP_ENVIRONMENT_BASE + "merchandising.items.base_url");

    httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

}
```

Is there any special annotation or something I need to do to get this to actually implement the `EnvironmentAware` interface?

Comment: Ofcourse it is `null` in the constructor... How should a setter be called on an object that doesn't even exists yet.

Comment: How does one mark a question as solved?  @M.Deinum ...   That fixed the problem....

Comment: You can delete your own questions

Comment: delete your question or post your own answer and accept it. But don't edit to add 'solved'. (Ideally M. Deinum should have anwser in an answer and not in comment and you should have accepted it. Anyway it's a trivial case so you can safely delete)

Comment: I posted the answer, but it said I have to wait 2 days before accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

One often gets so wrapped up in "configuration" issues that a blinding glimpse of the obvious escapes one.

M. Deinum gave me that obvious answer.  In my code, I am attempting to access a variable in the Constructor that will be set later.  When I moved the initialization of those variables into another method, the "setEnvironment()" method was called before I used the environment variable.

Thanks